# No sound after updating from 11.10 to 12.04

Tags: 11.10, 12.04, sound

Hi I updated a friends computer from 11.10 to 12.04 and the sound stopped working in the built-in speakers. The computer is a Sony Vaio PCG-2J1L. I tried using the guide found here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HdaIntelSoundHowto and still no luck.

```
$cat /proc/asound/card0/codec* | grep Codec
Codec: Realtek ALC889

$cat /proc/asound/card0/pcm0c/info
card: 0
device: 0
subdevice: 0
stream: CAPTURE
id: ALC889 Analog
name: ALC889 Analog 
subname: subdevice #0
class: 0
subclass: 0
subdevices_count: 1
subdevices_avail: 1
```

cat /proc/asound/card0/codec* output can be found here http://paste.ubuntu.com/1043188/

If anymore information is needed just let me know and ill post it here. Thank you in advance for any help with this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching around the forums found this answer

Append

```
/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

with the following line:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=generic
```

rebooted and all sound worked

Comment: This answer is a keeper!

Answer (score 1):

The sound on my 32bit 12.04 Xubuntu system suddenly went quiet.

Unknown as to why it suddenly changed.

I use an ancient Audigy card, but the laptop should be much simpler.

This is how I solved it...

Downloaded QasMixer, ran it and discovered that I had two "Analog Mix", one turned on and the other turned off.  I switched them and sound returned.

Hope this easy fix works for you... (*Click on image and select open in a new tab/window for better view*)

[image]

Comment: [IMG]http://i45.tinypic.com/r22eyt.png[/IMG]

Comment: Ok so i installed qas and played with a little but still no luck. Here is a screenshot of my QAS layout [link](http://i45.tinypic.com/r22eyt.png). If you have any more suggestions please let me know. Thanks for the help.